# What is the meaning of the math symbol "$\theta$", as in "$\theta(31\pi-t)\,\theta(t-27\pi)$"?

Tags: functions, notation

What would be the meaning of the sign "$\theta$" that looks like a slashed zero?

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: it is a greek letter named Theta $\theta$. Its used in number theory functins but I don't think that this is the case.

Comment: Is there a context for this equation?

Comment: It’s probably defined earlier in the same place where you found this formula. Where did this come from?

Comment: You seem to be using Wolfram and I believe this is the [Heaviside Theta](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HeavisideTheta.html) function.

Comment: Thank you Peter Foreman, that was the link I needed.

Comment: Alex R Yes I need to plot this function in java code. https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=butterfly+curve

Answer (score 0):

I have seen it used for a unit step function, which is $1$ if the argument is positive and $0$ if the argument is negative.  For most uses you don't care what happens at $0$, but it is often taken to be $\frac 12.$  In your example, the expression would be $0$ outside the interval $[27\pi, 31\pi]$ and the theta functions would multiply to $1$ within that interval and $\frac 12$ at the endpoints.